# How is $f(t)=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{itx}}{2}dx=\frac{\sin t}{t}?$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

How is $$f(t)=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{itx}}{2}dx=\frac{\sin t}{t}?$$

I feel like this would require some knowledge of complex analysis, which I just started taking, so I was hoping that someone could explain this. Integrals are far from foreign to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{e^{itx}}2\,dx & = \left .\frac 1{it}\frac {e^{itx}}2\right|_{x=-1}^{x=1}\\
& = \frac 1{it}\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}2\\
& = \frac 1t\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}\\
& = \frac{\sin t}t.
\end{align}$$

Comment: In words: "assume $e^{itx}$ behaves exactly like exponentials have always behaved, $\int_a^bdx~e^{kx} = (e^{kb} - e^{ka})/{k}.$ Then observe that $(e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta})/(2i) = \sin\theta.$ With those two steps, the result is trivial."

Comment: I did much the same when I saw that you had deleted your comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** No complex analysis required. Note that $e^{itx} = \cos(tx) + i \sin(tx).$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 e^{itx}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \text{cos} (tx)+i\text{sin}(tx) dx=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\frac{\text{sin}(tx)}{t}\Bigg]_{-1}^1+\frac{1}{2}i\Bigg[\frac{-\text{cos}(tx)}{t}\Bigg]_{-1}^1=\frac{\text{sint}}{t}$